Why does the resolution of my Prometheus query impact the actual increase/value I get back?
I was graphing the increase in value over time in Prometheus, and everything was working great. I can see the metric increasing from 1 to 3 (an increase of 2) within the last 90 days as expected (he graph looks a little weird because of the way Prometheus interpolates things, but I get that and that's OK):

Querying these metrics over 90 days is kinda slow though, and I really don't need down-to-the-second resolution here (per week or per day would be fine) so I was trying to speed up the query by changing the resolution to 1 day... but then things get weird:

I can't understand why changing the resolution of the data I'm fetching would change the actual end result? The whole increase is well within the 90 day total window... so why doesn't the 1 day resolution show the increase() at all? It's just at 0?
Can anyone help me understand what's going on here? (And, ideally, how to fix it?)

Query increase(metric[90d:15m]) takes values of the metric for last 90 days, one per each 15 minutes, and the calculates increase shown in those values. And since first visible value is 1 and latest 3 increase is calculated to be (approximately) 2 continuously.
Similarly query increase(metric[90d:1d]) takes values of the metric for last 90 days, one per each day. Samples that are taken, are taken on 00:00 UTC. Based on graph you provided samples for metric with resolution 1d are all equal to 3. Thus, increase is calculated to be 0.
If you'll query you input metric (without calling increase function) with resolution of graph (Res. (s)) set to 86400, you'll see sample that are used by increase in your second case.

Ah, this is helpful. So this is essentially a "metric didn't start at zero" issue? if the metric had been initialized to zero, back 60 days ago, then both would show the same value then?

@KeithPalmerJr., never thought about this from that perspective, but yes. If it were initialized with 0 for sufficiently long (not even 90 days, any time period longer than resolution would do), you'd get increase greater than 0.
